# jest - error with watch mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, jestjs

I am using `Jest 21.2.1` to run my tests for a react application. Strangely when I run `jest --watch` (as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html)) to watch test cases for any change, I get an error as below

```
Determining test suites to run...Error: This promise must be present when running with -o.
```

I tried to check the Jest-CLI and found that the function is expecting two parameters and one of them is promise which is not passed in this case (Not sure how can I pass that). Maybe some missing config?

Any suggestion will be helpful to fix this.

```
getTestPaths(
  globalConfig,
  changedFilesPromise)
  {var _this2 = this;return _asyncToGenerator(function* () {
     const paths = globalConfig.nonFlagArgs;
     if (globalConfig.onlyChanged) {
        if (!changedFilesPromise) {
           throw new Error('This promise must be present when running with -o.');
        }

        return _this2.findTestRelatedToChangedFiles(changedFilesPromise);
     }
```

Note: It might be related to issue reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2979).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're running it in a Git repo (initialised with `git init`). Otherwise it doesn't know how to get only the changed files.

If you don't want to run tests only on changed files, you can use `--watchAll`, which runs all the tests.

Comment: true i had a react project without `git` initialisation. It is a bit weird though, but well it works now. Thanks a lot :)